# AudioJS not working IE8 - Runtime Error

Tags: internet-explorer, runtime-error, html5-audio, playback

I am using AudioJS (http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/) to add audio to a website I am designing. I have it functioning, but for some reason it's not working in IE8 - works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

The `javascript` looks like: http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/themes/choosedumont/audio/audio.js

The `code` looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    audiojs.createAll();
});
</script>
```

The `tag` looks like:

```
<audio src="http://www.weatheranswer.com/public/frank_sinatra_let_it_snow.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

**Internet Explorer 8's error message:**

---

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0)
Timestamp: Fri, 8 Feb 2013 22:41:12 UTC

Message: Unknown runtime error
Line: 272
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: http://new.joshrodg.com/wp-content/themes/choosedumont/audio/audio.js

---

**Line 272 reads**: element.outerHTML = wrapper.outerHTML;

I traced the error down, just don't know how to fix the bug...anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it!!

Not sure what happened, but I ended up using a different player (http://mediaelementjs.com/)

I started off using the MediaElementJS player, but for some reason it didn't apply the skin to any of my audio files. This time I added it to my theme manually (instead of using the plugin - which is what I used originally)

I also incorporated the skin: http://www.onedesigns.com/freebies/custom-mediaelement-js-skin, which took a little bit of time because that one is only available as a plugin.

Not sure why the AudioJS script didn't work (because it should have) and I'm not sure why the MediaElementJS script didn't work as a plugin (because it should have), all in all I'm glad I have something that finally works, is cross-browser compatible, and looks nice with or without flash.

Thanks,
Josh